# python convert svg with cairosvg results empty image

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg

I want to convert a svg to a png via python [cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/) . Here is my example code:

```
from cairosvg import svg2png
img_svg='<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/BACKGROUND/BACKGROUND%204-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/WINGS/MECHA-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/BODY%20COLOR/HUMAN-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/FACE%20PATTERN/MECHA%20LINES%201-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/EYES/CRY-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/EYE%20WEAR/PATTERNED%20BLINDFOLD-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/MOUTH/PACIFIER-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmfHhxDFJ7VS4ZkF3rrQC1tbRLXMbLdN8ruaB2zqyouUN8/NOSE/DEFAULT-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/HAIR/DREAD%20BLACK-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/HEAD/HALO-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmeuPTvjqUhhJCo462atgKrM9tv3iohSZaVtePNDeUQvkr/BODY%20INNER/LONG%20NECK%20X%20RED-min.png "/><image href="https://mythcity.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmfHhxDFJ7VS4ZkF3rrQC1tbRLXMbLdN8ruaB2zqyouUN8/BODY%20OUTER/PUFFER%20JACKET%20BLACK-min.png "/></svg>' 
svg2png(bytestring=img_svg,write_to='/src/temp.png',output_width=500, output_height=500)
```

The result is an empty image.

When rendering on a online svg renderer it works like a charm (i tried it with [svgviewer](https://www.svgviewer.dev/))

Python Version: Python 3.10.5 (main, Jun 24 2022, 02:43:59) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux

Cairosvg Version: 2.5.2

Comment: The SVG is a png already though, it just contains a load of png images. I imagine cairosvg only supports images as data uris anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out with a workaround.

- Extacting all image links from the svg
- Merging & save them together with python pil

This solved my problem.